# Cassandra - Does CQLSSTableWriter support writing to multiple column families concurrently in one JVM instance?

Tags: java, cassandra, database, nosql

I'm running Cassandra 2.1.0 as my client due to 2.0.9 not supporting concurrent writers on the same table, 2.0.9 on the cluster.

I can use concurrent CQLSStableWriter objects for a single CF in one JVM instance. However, when I try to use two CQLSStableWriter objects, one for each CF, for two CF's in one JVM instance, I receive the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unconfigured columnfamily <the second column family>
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter$Builder.getStatement(CQLSSTableWriter.java:460)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter$Builder.using(CQLSSTableWriter.java:391)
at CsvLoader.generateSSTables(CsvLoader.java:60)
at MultiThreadedCsvLoader$LoaderThread.run(MultiThreadedCsvLoader.java:93)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: unconfigured columnfamily avping_v2_file_sha2_id_idx
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftValidation.validateColumnFamily(ThriftValidation.java:115)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement$Parsed.prepare(ModificationStatement.java:730)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement$Parsed.prepare(ModificationStatement.java:724)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.getStatement(QueryProcessor.java:437)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter$Builder.getStatement(CQLSSTableWriter.java:449)
... 3 more
```

The code I am running is in short:

```
CQLSSTableWriter writer1 = CQLSSTableWriter.builder().inDirectory("keyspace/cf_1").forTable(<cf_1 create statement>).using(<cf_1 insert statement>).build();
CQLSSTableWriter writer2 = CQLSSTableWriter.builder().inDirectory("keyspace/cf_2").forTable(<cf_2 create statement>).using(<cf_2 insert statement>).build();
```

The error occurs during the second call of using(). The program has multiple threads, but I restricted to one thread for debugging.

Is multiple CQLSSTableWriters for multiple CF's in one JVM instance supported currently? Am I using the API correctly?

The reason I am writing to multiple CF's is that I need to build the main table and also one or more indices. sstableloader seems to be the recommended method for bulk loading. Are there any other decent methods to approach this problem if CQLSSTableWriter doesn't support my use case, such as loading the main table first and then using a CQL client to iterate over the rows in the main CF and inserting into the index? Or just switch to completely using CQL BATCH?

The first test data set is 10's of TB. The data is either in gzip'd text files or a Postgres database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

between writer1 and writer2 put you can insert this

```
import org.apache.cassandra.config.KSMetaData;
import org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema;
...
CQLSSTableWriter writer1 = CQLSSTableWriter.builder().inDirectory("keyspace/cf_1").forTable(<cf_1 create statement>).using(<cf_1 insert statement>).build();
... do your stuff with writer1....
// remove keyspace definition
KSMetaData ksm = Schema.instance.getKSMetaData("keyspace");
Schema.instance.clearKeyspaceDefinition(ksm);
CQLSSTableWriter writer2 = CQLSSTableWriter.builder().inDirectory("keyspace/cf_2").forTable(<cf_2 create statement>).using(<cf_2 insert statement>).build();
... do your stuff with writer2....
```

it worked for me
hope it helps

Comment: Not cool with such global shared state. But well done figuring out how to overcome it - your answer was a great help! (hopefully there are no "side-effects" :-)).